# Xcode 9: How to create XCUIElement instances using XCUIElementQuery?

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcode9-beta, xcode9

After watching the 2017 WWDC Xcode and [XCTest](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/409/) videos, I updated my tests to use latest additions in XCTests.

I recently upgraded to Xcode 9 Beta, runnning OS X Sierra 10.12.4

After this, all tests where I used [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement)() to create an element instance, failed.

**Example code line:**
*XCTAssertTrue(XCUIElement().scrollToElement(tablesQuery.cells.staticTexts["Featured"]).exists)*

**This is the error I get:**
*'init()' is unavailable: Use XCUIElementQuery to create XCUIElement instances.*

If you are curious what *scrollToElement()* is, it is a custom function to scroll to the element being queried, if it is not visible in current view.
It is part of a custom extension of XCUIElement I wrote.

As part of solution, can you suggest:
How XCUIElement instances are expected to be created now?

For reference:
**scrollToElement()**

```
open func scrollToElement(_ element: XCUIElement) -> XCUIElement {
    while !element.visible() {
        swipeUp()
    }
    return element
}

open func visible() -> Bool {
    guard self.exists && !self.frame.isEmpty else { return false }
    return XCUIApplication().windows.element(boundBy: 0).frame.contains(self.frame)
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to try to create an instance of `XCUIElement` at all? I think you should make `scrollToElement` a static method instead.

Comment: @AdamPro13 Good idea, but Inside `scrollToElement` I am using the `swipeUp()` method from XCUIElement, hence it can't be made static.

Comment: You can't just instantiate an instance of `XCUIElement` because they map to existing elements in the UI. If you created an element without it being associated with the UI, you wouldn't be able to do anything with it because it doesn't know anything.

Comment: Thank you Adam! I found a solution by using `XCUIApplication` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize XCUIElements directly - you must access them through XCUIApplication, which is a subclass of XCUIElement. If you call your scrolling method from XCUIApplication, it will work.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
XCTAssertTrue(app.scrollToElement(app.tables.cells.staticTexts["Featured"]).exists)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, you are my savior. I somehow missed noticing that `XCUIApplication` is a subclass of `XCUIElement`. Thank you so much!